# Kryonet: Client can't send and receive at the same time?

Tags: java, networking, kryonet

I'm making a game with Slick2D and using Kryonet for multiplayer. My architecture is set up so that all clients connect to a server, which is not playing the game itself (as opposed to a player running the client and the server in the same program). It's a 2D shooter, and everything works fine when only one client is playing. The issue appears when I connect another client.

Apparently the client can't send and receive at the same time. For example, if both clients are shooting their weapons at the same time, it will look like only that player is shooting on their own client, and the other player is idle. Likewise, if both players are moving, the other player won't move until the client player stops, and then the other will jump to its current position.

I've provided the code for the client and server listeners here:

```
public class ClientGameListener extends Listener {

protected Client owner;
protected MultiplayerClientGameState state;

public ClientGameListener(Client c, MultiplayerClientGameState state) {
    owner = c;
    this.state = state;
}

@Override
public void received(Connection connection, Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof PositionPacket) {
        state.adjustPlayerPosition((PositionPacket)obj);
    }
    else if(obj instanceof FirePacket) {
        state.scheduleFireListing((FirePacket)obj);
    }
    else if(obj instanceof ToggleWeaponPacket) {
        state.togglePlayerWeapon((ToggleWeaponPacket)obj);
    }
}
}

public class ServerGameListener extends Listener {

protected Server owner;
protected MultiplayerServerGameState state;

public ServerGameListener(Server s, MultiplayerServerGameState state) {
    owner = s;
    this.state = state;
}

@Override
public void received(Connection connection, Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof PositionPacket) {
        owner.sendToAllExceptTCP(connection.getID(), obj);
    }
    else if(obj instanceof FirePacket) {
        owner.sendToAllExceptTCP(connection.getID(), obj);
    }
    else if(obj instanceof ToggleWeaponPacket) {
        owner.sendToAllExceptTCP(connection.getID(), obj);
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas on why my client can't send and receive info at the same time, or how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending messages over **UDP**.